# Building Nested TypeScript Projects

Tags: typescript, vite

I'm using Typescript, React, and Vite.

This is my project structure. I have a `tsconfig.json` file at the root level. And I have a `public/tsconfig.worker.json` dedicated to my `public/serviceWorker.ts` file.

```
.
├── tsconfig.json
├── src/
│   └── constants/config.ts
└── public/
    ├── serviceWorker.ts
    └── tsconfig.worker.json
```

In my `public/serviceWorker.ts` file, I'm importing a variable from `src/constants/config.ts`.

```
// public/serviceWorker.ts

import Variable from "../src/constants/config";
```

I'm seeing this error in the import statement.

```
File '<path>/src/constants/config.ts' is not listed within the file list of project '<path>/public/tsconfig.worker.json'. Projects must list all files or use an 'include' pattern.
```

Below are my tsconfigs.

```json
// root tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2022", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,

    // ...
  },
  "include": ["src", "svg.d.ts", "public/serviceWorker.ts"],
  "references": [
    { "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" },
    { "path": "./public/tsconfig.worker.json" }
  ]
}
```

```json
// public/tsconfig.worker.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "../",
    "composite": true,
    "module": "es2022",
    "noEmit": false,
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "lib": ["WebWorker", "ES2022"],
  }
}
```

Also, I'm able to build (`"build": "tsc && vite build"`) but the build includes `serviceWorker.ts` and `tsconfig.worker.json` files in the output like below.

```
.
└── dist/
    ├── assets/
    ├── serviceWorker.ts
    └── tsconfig.worker.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of your project is somewhat confusing. It seems to me, like you try to build the whole project from the root, expecting that `tsconfig.json` will be applied for the `src` folder and it will be merged with `public/tsconfig.worker.json` for the `public/serviceWorker.ts` file. But, when you run build `public/tsconfig.worker.json` is applied to the `public/serviceWorker.ts` independently from the `tsconfig.json`, which means it doesn't know about `{ "include": "public/serviceWorker.ts" }`. Try to add `{ "include": "serviceWorker.ts" }` into `public/tsconfig.worker.json` and remove `{ "include": "public/serviceWorker.ts" }` from the root `tsconfig.json`.

Now about `dist` folder. [This is the default `vite` behavior](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets#the-public-directory). `public` folder is supposed to be used for static assets only that don't require compilation, so you should think about putting your `serviceWorker.ts` somewhere else. I would try to place into `src`, since as far as I can see, you compile it anyway, so it's not a static asset. [`vite` knows how to handle worker files out of the box](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets#importing-script-as-a-worker).

Overall, I'd merge both `tsconfigs` into one and put `serviceWorker.ts` into `src` folder, e.g. `src/workers/serviceWorker.ts`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and relevant links.